# Android accessibility talkback function does not read my views description in the right order

Tags: android, accessibility, android-constraintlayout, talkback

Here the structure of my xml file. I've numbered the order in which it reads the content descriptions.Note worthy is that the TitleCardView's has inflated rows of data in it (they read just fine).

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView/>1
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView/>2
        <com.android.module.uicomponents.card.TitleCardView/>3
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView/>5
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView/>6
        <com.android.module.uicomponents.card.TitleCardView/>4
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```